# Map of ragweed infested countries

Tags: allergy, allergen, environmental-climate, geography, database

I have a very serious ragweed allergy and I am living in Hungary which is pretty much super infested. 
I started wondering which countries are affected by this lovely plant, because I don't want to have vacation in the season in these places.

So the question is: is there a map that shows its affected areas? 
If not, is there a publicly available international database of affected areas?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.polleninfo.org/fileadmin/template/img/chartimages/currency/resized/POAC_06_1.gif

According to the little number on the lower left, this is from 2012. The situation is worse than I expected in Europe. Also, there is a map from the states:

http://www.allamericanallergy.com/images/Ragweed%20Pollen%20Map%2008-25-2014.jpg

It will be so cool to find a map from the whole globe though.

Comment: A great answer to a great question (+1 each) :-). The second link seems to be broken it doesn't work. Can you fix it? I think many users will find this answer very useful, thanks!